# Query Builder in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

On my query builder in Visual Studio 2010 I created a command that captures patient info with the 'x' condition.

That 'LIKE' command filters the patient's however in a specific cell there is multiple data entry for conditions, is there any way that I can display only the entered condition instead of showing all for example in one cell I have "allergic rhinitis / mild / bronchial asthma" now what will happen is if I filter the word "MILD" it will only display "MILD" in that cell and  or is there any workaround for this? and also... on my form i want it in parametrized query so I should use "?" but I don't know where to place it to make the code work...

What I have right now is

```
SELECT      patientinfo.caseno, 
            patientinfo.lname, 
            patientinfo.fname, 
            patientinfo.mname, 
            presentworking.allergicrhin

FROM        patientinfo 

INNER JOIN  presentworking 
    ON      patientinfo.caseno = presentworking.caseno

WHERE       presentworking.allergicrhin LIKE '%MODERATE TO SEVERE%' -- < = = = = (where to place the '?' here to make it parametized...
```

Comment: Are you using Microsoft SQL Server, or a different SQL engine?

Comment: In case of multiple options in the field, is there always a specific separator you could use? Above you used a forward slash, is that always the case?

For the parameter, I'd recommend transferring the SQL code to a stored procedure which accepts an input parameter.

Comment: Hi rowland i am using an access database, the query builder is built in in visual studio 2010 thank you

Comment: hi schmitz is there any way that you could somewhat give me an idea how to do that? Btw i just used that "/" to separate the words.